# Unable to resume Triggered Send, says "The prior selected Sender Profile has been deleted or is not verified"

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I am trying to re-enable a recently paused Triggered Send, however when I try and do this a really generic error is returned saying:

> Failed to start the selected triggered send(s): A problem occurred Starting the following Triggered Sends. Please contact Customer Service for additional information.Name: Onboarding_Journey External Key: Onboarding_Journey_ ErrorID : Exception occurred during [UpdateTriggeredSendDefinition] ErrorID = 901092845

When I click into the Triggered Send itself, I get the following error displayed:
[image]

When I review the Sender Profile and the Delivery profile, they do exist. The Sender profile email address is also verified.

Can someone tell me why this could be occuring, I have a case raised with Salesforce about this but I was hoping maybe this might be an issue someone else has come across (and get back to me sooner than SF usually takes)

Comment: @deploymentFailure....did you check if those sender profile email address has been verified?...here is the link for reference - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000353007&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the profile in which the classification is really configured with is not verified.

However if you open the classification, only the profiles that are verified are in the drop down box. Which means the profile you previously configured is not showing.

If you re-save the classification it will change the sender profile to the currently selected, which is different than what you chose previously

Or you can go look at your profiles and verify the email in each one that is not verified